# Finite-Element Method: Question on stability for equation $u_{t}+au_{xxx}=f$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am trying to determine the stability of the PDE

$$u_{t}+au_{xxx}=f$$

Given the finite-element scheme

$$\frac{u_{j}^{n+1}-u_{j}^{n}}{\Delta t}+a \frac{u_{j+2}^{n}-3u_{j+1}^{n}+3u_{j}^{n}-u_{j-1}^{n}}{(\Delta x) ^{3}}=f_{j}^{n}$$

and constant s

$$s=\frac{a \Delta t}{(\Delta x)^{3}}$$

My problem is that I don't think this equation is elliptic, parabolic, or hyperbolic, and those are the only ones I know how to show stability for. Can anyone help?

Comment: This is not finite element...

Comment: This is finite difference method

Comment: This _may be_ a finite element method. It often happens that finite elements and finite differences are in fact equivalent. See: http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/sunall/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

There is one method, it is called Von Neumann analysis.Instead of $u^{n+1}_{i}$ and $u^{n}_{i}$ you should substitute one harmonic from exponential Fourier series expansion:$u_{k}^{n}=c_{k,n}e^{ipx}$; $u^{n+1}_{k}=c_{k,n+1}e^{ipx}$;$(p=\frac{\pi k}{l})$ - depends on how have you your function expanded. For the rest values:

$$u^{n}_{k+1}=c_{k,n}e^{ip(x+\Delta x)},u^{n}_{k+2}c_{k,n}e^{ip(x+2\Delta x)},u^{n}_{k-1}=c_{k,n}e^{ip(x-\Delta x)},u^{n}_{k-2}=c_{k,n}e^{ip(x-2\Delta x)} $$

Now you substitute them to numerical scheme:

$$\frac{(c_{k,n+1}-c_{k,n})e^{ipx}}{\Delta t}+a\frac{c_{k,n}(e^{ip(x+2\Delta x)}-3e^{ip(x+\Delta x)}+3e^{ipx}-e^{ip(x-\Delta x)})}{\Delta x^3}=f^{n}_{i} $$

After that you submit $\frac{c_{k,n+1}}{c_{k,n}}=g$ -- the "factor of transition" and constant $s$. After that you simplify this equation in order to get 
$$g=F(\Delta x,\Delta t, a) $$

This equality shows, for which parameters is this scheme stable or not